# Spring Java config specified Beans won't initialize

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, config

I've read Spring In Action, and prefer Java config over XML config. So I used Java config to write my app, but our deployment environment requires me to use XML config. So I wrote an XML config, and it's only function is to import the root Java config.

The Java config code looks like this:

```
package com.somegroup.app;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.tianchengsys.crawlers.cqs")
public class AppCtxConfig {

    @Bean
    public SomeType aSomeType() {
           return new SomeType()
    }

}
```

and the XML config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:dubbo="http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo
    http://code.alibabatech.com/schema/dubbo/dubbo.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="com.somegroup.app.AppCtxConfig" lazy-init="false" />

</beans>
```

When I created a `ClasspathXmlContext("classpath:spring-context.xml")` in Eclipse, the SomeType bean defined in Java config is initialized, and registered to springs ApplicationContext. But when I deployed this app (all dependencies are in a lib directory), the AppCtxConfig bean defined in the XML config was just treated an ordinary bean (not configuration).

It was created, but the beans defined in it were not initialized. Spring some times warned the someType method in the Java config should be static. I did changed it to static, it also didn't work.

Comment: Did you try using <context:component-scan base-package="com.somegroup.app" />? You can refer [this article on how to refer java configuration in config xml](http://memorynotfound.com/mixing-xml-java-config-spring/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating `AppCtxConfig` as a regular bean, which it isn't.

As the commentor suggested, add the component-scan on and set base-package to the package where your config class is located in:

```
<!-- Scan the JavaConfig -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.somegroup.app" />
```

If your app package is the root package, with all subpackages inside, add a new config package and move the `AppCtxConfig` inside it.

So add:

```
<!-- Scan the config package with AppCtxConfig inside it -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.somegroup.app.config" />
```